# Suggestion Selection in IE

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a requirement to fill Manager (I.e Hall ss(wa)) detail in a web page. So that I need to enter the first name (Hall) the page shows managers with same first name (Like: HALL ss(wa), HALL kk(sd),..etc) and then I need to click the manager what I need (Hall ss(wa)). We have the full name of the manager. But if we enter the full name the page will not accept. This page only accept the click on the suggestions (Refer image - Hall)

[image]

The VBA code as follows:

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ServiceManagerName").Value = "Hall"
Set ElementCol = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ajax_listOfOptions").innerText
For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link = " HALL ss(wa)" Then
Link.Click
End If
Next
```

while running the code throw an error like "Compile Error: Object Required".
The html code as follows (Refer image - html)
[image]

```
<div id="ajax_listOfOptions" style="top: 1128px; left: 193px; display: block;">
<div id="105827" class="optionDiv">HALL ss(wa)</div>
<div id="102147" class="optionDivSelected">HALL kk(sd)</div>
<div id="
" class="optionDiv">
</div>
```

Please can anyone help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Link` is not an object. It's of type `String`. I suspect that's whats throwing the error. Also, it is very highly recomended to not use reserved words as your variable names (i.e. **`Link`**)

Answer (score 0):

Check manually if the page works in IE as you want. If it do try this:

```
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ServiceManagerName").Value = "Hall"
Set ElementCol = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ajax_listOfOptions").getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each LinkCheck In ElementCol
  If LinkCheck.innerText = " HALL ss(wa)" Then
    Link.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```